# Column-wise count output in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have formed the below table using the below SQL query.

```
STATE  count(goo)  AVG_SAL  count(SCOPE)  AVG_SAL  count(FB) AVG_SAL count(PAL)  AVG_SAL
KN        1          5500        --            --          --     --        --         --
IN       --           --          1           6000        1        3999     --         --
AR        1          7000         --            --         1       8250      --        --
CL        1          6000        --             --       --          --       1      4500
```

```
SELECT
  state,
  GooCount,
  GooCount   / Total AS AVG_GOO,
  sCOPECount,
  SCOPECount / Total AS AVG_SCOPE,
  FBCOunt, 
  FBCount    / Total AS AVG_FB,
  PALCount,
  PALCount   / Total AS AVG_PAL
FROM
(
    select
      state,
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'GOO'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GooCount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'SCOPE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCOPECount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'FB'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FBCount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN COMPANY_NAME = 'PAL'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PALCount,    
      COUNT(*) AS total
    from company_details 
    where company_status = 'OPEN'
    group by state order by state
) AS sub;
```

However I would like to form an output like this.

```
STATE  count(goo)  AVG_SAL  count(SCOPE)  AVG_SAL  count(FB) AVG_SAL count(PAL)  AVG_SAL
KN        1          5500        --            --          --     --        --         --
IN       --           --          1           6000        1        3999     --         --
AR        1          7000         --            --         1       8250      --        --
CL        1          6000        --             --       --          --       1      4500
Total    3           18500        1             6000        2      12249     1        4500
```

I want to do a column wise count.

Comment: The totals row should be one query and the rest of the rows should be another query.

Comment: @Krish `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` is exactly what you need , like Serge answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Group + Rollup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was just answering a few "Sql server" questions, and I didn't notice your question was about oracle. (Stack overflow "interresting questions" is just tricking me now and then).